# JRules comparation

Tags: java, rule, ilog

I'm writting a Java application to compare the changes done in a JRules jar. In this application I will compare the original jar, with the new jar with changes. For this, I'm using ILOG api. Well, the problem it's that I don't know exactly how to compare one rule with other in order to know if it's the same or not. I think that maybe I could compare between conditions and actions, but I'm not sure how it works. Here is my code:

```
//Assume the rulesets are correctly initializated
JRule[] rulesOrig = ruleSetOriginal.getAllRules();
JRule[] rulesChanged = ruleSetChanged.getAllRules();
for(int i=0; i<rulesOrig.length;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<rulesOrig[i].getConditionCount();j++){
        if(rulesOrig[i].getConditionAt(j).equals(rulesChanged[i].getConditionAt(j))){
        .....
        }
    }
}
```

This comparison, with .equals() methos returns always false. I think it's not implemented.
anyone knows how to make this comparison? The objective it's compare the changes made between two JRules jar version, if you know another form for due this, please tell me about it.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It will help if you can specify in which versions are you working on.

Comment: I'm using an old version of Ilog JRules. It's 6.7.3. Thanks!

Comment: jrules-bres-execution-6.7.3, jrules-engine-6.7.3.jar and sam-1.3.jar. Can you help me please?

Comment: I was referring to the fact that this type of information should be added as it is probably version dependend. Anyway, you can try to write your own Comparator for the rules (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).